# Sliding overlaying panel

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, mvvm, prism

I have an ItemsControl set up in my View and it generates items (duh!) which are clickable. When a user clicks/selects one of the items, I would like a panel/grid to slide from the left to the right and overlay (occupy the whole space). How can I implement this via MVVM with the slide animation? I know how to code it so that the grid appears with the correct data and all by setting a style DataTrigger but it is horrible as it just appears, no animation what so ever.

PS: since some will ask, I just set up a new bool item in my ViewModel like:

```
public bool ShowGrid
{
    get { return _showGrid; }
    set
    {
        _showGrid = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => ShowGrid);
    }
}
```

And the DataTrigger just says: if ShowGrid = true then visibility="Visible". Nothing fancy.

How can this be coded so that when the DataTrigger knows to show/hide the grid, it slides it in/out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several variants of this implementation. I would have done so. I would create a *attached* dependency property, which was set to `True`, the event is triggered when you click on an item. In `DataTrigger` according to the dependency property, the animation would show sliding animation.

The sample of *attached* dependency property:

```
public static class PanelBehaviors
{
    public static void SetIsSliding(DependencyObject target, bool value)
    {
        target.SetValue(IsSlidingProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSlidingProperty =
                                              DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsSliding",
                                              typeof(bool),
                                              typeof(PanelBehaviors),
                                              new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsSliding));

    private static void OnIsSliding(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewValue is bool && ((bool)e.NewValue) == true)
        {
            // You can do the operations on the object for which the property is set,
            // for example, for panel - set Visible
        }
    }
}
```

In behind code (for example: in event handler), you can set value for attached dependency property like that:

```
PanelBehaviours.SetIsSliding(SomeControl, Value // True or False);
```

Or in XAML:

```
<SomeControl local:PanelBehaviours.SetIsSliding="True" ... />
```

In `OnIsSliding` you can apply animation, but I would do it on the XAML side. Show panel can be done on the side by dependency properties or animation.

The sample of `DataTrigger` and Slide-animation:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=MyPanel, Path=(local:MyDependencyClass.IsSliding), Mode=OneWay}" Value="True">
    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <!-- Here you can show the panel, or use additional animation -->
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetName="MyPanel" Storyboard.TargetProperty="VerticalAlignment">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            <VerticalAlignment>Bottom</VerticalAlignment>
                        </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
</DataTrigger>
```

In WPF no animation alignment, the only thing that can come up - it `ThicknessAnimation` (using `Margin`). But you can use the `DiscreteObjectKeyFrame` to set the alignment. Above is a simple demonstration in which to `Panel` set VerticalAlignment in Bottom.

In principle, all of these options should not contradict the pattern MVVM.

Please see my examples of implementations with attached properties and alignment animations:

[wpf ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames setting the left value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18415846/wpf-objectanimationusingkeyframes-setting-the-left-value/18417496#18417496)

[Animation limited by panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17898166/animation-limited-by-panel/17898552#17898552)

[How to clear the contents of a PasswordBox when login fails without databinding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17750564/how-to-clear-the-contents-of-a-passwordbox-when-login-fails-without-databinding/17751025#17751025)

[How to inherit Button behaviour in WPF style?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17652114/how-to-inherit-button-behaviour-in-wpf-style/17653668#17653668)

[Quit application from a user Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17626998/quit-application-from-a-user-control/17628565#17628565)

Comment: amazing coding. taught me a lot there